# Cakephp2.2 files to a Cakephp3.7 installation for easy migration :)

Tags: cakephp, migration, php-7, php-5.6

I am very new to CakePHP.

I just joined a company that is having an eCommerce site running on cakephp2.2. It was very slow. I suggested upgrading the PHP version to 7.2 from 5.6 to make the performance a bit faster. But when I tried that the previous developer has used /e with preg_replace in about 13K places. I don't want to spend time to change all of that. So I thought I will move this CakePHP2.2 files to CakePHP3.7 installation. I installed a CakePHP3.7  with PHP7 in the Nginx server and the skeleton is working all fine. But I am getting all kinds of errors when I copied the login controller from the old version to a new version.
First one being :

> Component class SessionComponent could not be found.
>   Cake\Controller\Exception\MissingComponentException

So my questions are

1. Will copying files from 2.2 to 3.7 work in any condition?
2. Is there a tool to do this form me(the current code is all messed up without proper MVC pattern used)
3. Is the only way is rewriting the app from scratch to be compatible with 3.7

Please help.

Comment: easy migration: bake fresh app

Comment: @Salines: so you are saying rewrite the entire app on 3.7?

Comment: yes, I say rewrite the entire app